# Blocking an outbound port for a bridge'd nat'd inteface

Tags: iptables, nat, bridge

eth0 and wlan0 are bridged to br0, and have access to the outside world through eth1 and NAT.

I'd like to block an outbound port on wlan0, but leave it open for eth0.

Comment: On what hardware? Linksys, netgear,cicso, or etc? Model number?  Depending on the hardware you may or may not have that option.

Comment: wlan0 is some atheros chipset, running on ath9k, and eth0 is i210-V @cybernard